# Advice for reviewing edits

Tags: discussion, editing

I just became eligible to approve pending edits and would like some advice.  At the time of writing, this post has a pending edit:

[Finding similarities between images](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/25660/best-practices-in-php/25770#25770)

The edit changes the code posted in an answer - in a cooperative way, I'm not implying any bad intentions.  But is this the best way to proceed?  Should the editor have posted a comment instead, suggesting an improvement?  In this case what is my best response - to reject the edit or to skip it (leave it for someone else to deal with)?

Comment: For future reference, the pending edit you're talking about is http://codereview.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/9103.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, if you're unsure, you should skip it, that's exactly what the button is for.

For this specific edit, my personal opinion is that it should be rejected. I think edits on CR answers are useful when they are relatively small, unambiguous improvements, not rewriting a significant part of the code in the answer. I think posting a separate answer would be better for that.

Answer (score 8):

To my mind, the biggest problem is comment like this:

```
// Pi> Just noting that I edited this line too.
```

You can edit someone's answer to improve it, but it should feel like a cohesive answer. If you've got parts written and explicitly marked as from a secondary source that's a good sign it shouldn't have been edited in.